# Passing in References vs. Pointers

Tags: c++

I am getting an error when I pass in **newTemp** to **setEmergencyContact()**. The error I get is in regards to:

```
temp->Contact::setEmergencyContact(newTemp);
```

> "error: no matching function call to 'Contact::setEmergencyContact(*&Contact)'"

So my question is: If you have to create a object by using a pointer, how do you pass the object to a function that uses a reference not a pointer?

```
 Contact generateRandomContact(){
        // The name will be created with
        // generateRandomName() and phone number will be created with
        // generateRandomNumber(). Using the above random function,
        // with 50% probability assign a new Contact as the emergencyContact
        // of the one just generated. Otherwise leave it NULL (default).
        // Then return this Contact.

Contact* temp = new Contact;
temp->Contact::changeName(generateRandomName());
temp->Contact::changeNumber(generateRandomNumber());
    if(myrand(11) % 2 != 0){
      Contact* newTemp = new Contact;
      temp->Contact::setEmergencyContact(newTemp);
   }

return *temp;  
}
```

Emergency Contact Function:

```
void Contact::setEmergencyContact(Contact & _emergencyContact){
Contact* changeEmergencys = new Contact;
changeEmergencys = emergencyContact->getEmergencyContact();
}
```

Comment: Way too much `new`, did you mean to tag this `java`? (Obviously not, but please, you have to get rid of these useless pointers)

Comment: A temp that gets new'ed seems a bit fishy to me.. does `setEmergencyContact()` take owner ship and delete it later? Otherwise you get a memory leak with new. `newTemp` and `temp` both look like very likely memory leaks.

Comment: You seem to have several typos in your code, like using `emergencyContact` instead of `_emergencyContact` and similar.

Comment: @RaphaelMiedl it does delete later, sorry for not including that code, and user35443 I will rename them, its probably better to be more clear in my code.

Comment: @grillo modern C++ code should never use owned raw pointers (and some people even use a separate class for borrowed raw pointers), and entirely avoid `new`/`delete` in favor of `make_unique`/`make_shared` or just owning objects by value.

Answer (score 0):

Dereference it:

```
temp->setEmergencyContact(*newTemp)
```

Comment: That worked, I am still having trouble grasping the concept of pointers with functions. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Contact::setEmergencyContact(Contact & _emergencyContact)
```

Should be either just

```
void Contact::setEmergencyContact(Contact * _emergencyContact)
```

to work with your code, still using `->` instead of `.`.

However, if you want to modify the pointer itself, you can use

```
void Contact::setEmergencyContact(Contact* & _emergencyContact) {
    Contact* changeEmergencys = new Contact;
    changeEmergencys = _emergencyContact->getEmergencyContact();
}
```

Note that if you dereferenced it, you would have to use `.` instead of `->`

```
void Contact::setEmergencyContact(Contact & _emergencyContact) {
    Contact* changeEmergencys = new Contact;
    changeEmergencys = _emergencyContact.getEmergencyContact();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit the function to take a pointer instead:

```
void Contact::setEmergencyContact(Contact * _emergencyContact)
```

Or dereference the passing pointer as zmbq suggested.

I see that you are using much new and delete I can't help myself but to recommend smart pointers and minimize the use of new and delete.